# android swipe to the right and left gridView

Tags: android, gridview, swipe, swipe-gesture

I have a gridview that displays the product and I want change products to the swipe but I do not recognize the movements.
my class extends BaseMenuActivity and baseMenuActivity extends Activity
I took several tutorial but I still can not manage the movements

```
public class GalleryProductActivity extends BaseMenuActivity{

public final String imageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/galaxyv2Img/";
private String nomenclature;
private String activite;
private String code;
private GridView gridView;
private GalleryProductAdapter adapter;
private DatabaseHelper myDb;
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private int max,min;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    max = 10;
    min = 0;
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    nomenclature = intent.getStringExtra("nomenclature");
    activite = intent.getStringExtra("activite");
    code = intent.getStringExtra("code");

    adapter = new GalleryProductAdapter(this,getData());
    gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridViewGallery);
    gridView.setAdapter(adapter);

    MyGestureListener listener = new MyGestureListener(GalleryProductActivity.this);
    gridView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    listener.setSwipeGestureCallBack(this);
}

@Override
public void onSwipe(String direction) {
    // handle cases here
}

private ArrayList<GalleryProductItem> getData() {
    final ArrayList<GalleryProductItem> imageItems = new ArrayList<>();
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    db = myDb.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(" SELECT reference,libelle FROM Produit WHERE nomenclature IS NOT NULL ANd rd IS NULL AND activite IS '"+code+"' AND nomenclature  IS '"+nomenclature+"' ORDER BY id LIMIT "+min+","+max+";",null);
    System.out.println(cursor.getCount());
    int cpt = 0;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            System.out.println(cursor.getString(0) +"\n"+ cursor.getString(1));
            imageItems.add(new GalleryProductItem("file:" +imageDirectory+cursor.getString(0)+".jpg",cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(0)));
            cpt += 1;
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return imageItems;
}

@Override
public int getContentView() {
    return R.layout.activity_product_gallery;

}
```

MyGestureListener :

```
public class MyGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
private GestureDetector detector;
private SwipeGestureCallBack callBack;

public MyGestureListener(Context context) {
    detector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureDetector());
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
}

class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
    private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 20;
    private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;

    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY())) {
            if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                callBack.onSwipe("LEFT");
            } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                    && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                callBack.onSwipe("RIGHT");
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
        return true;
    }
}

public void setSwipeGestureCallBack(GalleryProductActivity callBack) {
    this.callBack = callBack;
}

public interface SwipeGestureCallBack {
    public void onSwipe(String direction);
}
```

}

Comment: I am also missing the movements.What you have will only populate GridView with GalleryProductItem. There is nothing here about swiping. Please search the site for "onSwipe" or "ActivitySwipeDetector" or even "swipe".

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. Create a class that extends `GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener` to handle the swipe gestures.

```
public class MyGestureListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
    private GestureDetector detector;
    private SwipeGestureCallBack callBack;

    public MyGestureListener(Context context) {
        detector = new GestureDetector(context, new MyGestureDetector());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
        private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 20;
        private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;

        public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
            if (Math.abs(e1.getX() - e2.getX()) > Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY())) {
                if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    callBack.onSwipe(Direction.LEFT);
                } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                        && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
                    callBack.onSwipe(Direction.RIGHT);
                }
            }

            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public void setSwipeGestureCallBack(SwipeGestureCallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    public interface SwipeGestureCallBack {
        public void onSwipe(Direction direction);
    }
}
```

Then on your `Activity` set your `GridView`'s onTouchListener to an instance of `MyGestureListener`

```
MyGestureListener listener = new MyGestureListener(MyActivity.this);
myGridView.setOnTouchListener(listener);
listener.setSwipeGestureCallBack(this);
```

Finally, handle the callbacks on your Activity by implementing `SwipeGestureCallBack`

```
@Override
    public void onSwipe(Direction direction) {
        // handle cases here
    }
```